# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrlang.gen_server'

Tags: python-3.x

Please note: Experience level - Beginner

Pyrlang was installed following the instructions provided [here](https://pyrlang.github.io/Pyrlang/build-library.html) and [here](https://github.com/Pyrlang/Term/issues/15).

```
   maxximiliann@Maxximiliann:~/Pyrlang-master$ make example10a
    PYTHONPATH=~/Pyrlang-master:~/Pyrlang-master/../Term PYRLANG_ENABLE_LOG_FORMAT=1 PYRLANG_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG python3 examples/elixir/e10.py
    Native term ETF codec library import failed, falling back to slower Python impl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "examples/elixir/e10.py", line 13, in <module>
        from pyrlang.gen_server import GenServer
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyrlang.gen_server'
    make: *** [Makefile:69: example10a] Error 1
```

What's causing these errors and how are they correctly resolved?

Comment: have you install the pyrlang ? try `pip install pyrlang`

Comment: Pyrlang was installed following these instructions: 
https://pyrlang.github.io/Pyrlang/build-library.html
https://github.com/Pyrlang/Term/issues/15

Comment: can you try this `pip3 list | grep pyrlang`? and what is the result?